# How to load an image generated by an aspx file into html

Tags: javascript

The following image: http://www.oscn.net/dockets/GetDocument.aspx?ct=tulsa&cn=SC-2011-361&bc=1014242988&fmt=tif

How would I go about downloading this image and displaying it in html using javascript?

Comment: Do you *need* it to be in JavaScript? Literally just `<img src="1014242988-20110128-125817-.tif" alt="" />` in HTML.

Comment: Does not work, this is an aspx file not anan image

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..
If you need to modify any properties of the image (size/color enhancement/etc.) use `new_elem.setAttribute('attribute', 'value');` Just like in HTML `<img attribute="value" />`

```js
var element = document.getElementById('mytargetlocation');

var new_elem = document.createElement('img');
var locationtoimage = 'https://www.sourcecertain.com/img/Example.png';
/*
Note: if your site uses HTTPS, this file will need to be loaded
over HTTPS, if it doesn't, you could just use the original
URL without downloading the image at all
*/
new_elem.setAttribute('src', locationtoimage);
new_elem.setAttribute('alt', 'image not found at specified URL');
element.append(new_elem);
```

```html
<div id="mytargetlocation"></div>
```